Optional argument
The \eval command works well when it was defined with \NewDocumentCommand{\eval}{mm}. When I try to make the second augument optional , an error appears :  Runaway argument?
\l_xcn_var_aa_fp  \par $\eval {4*5}$ \par \end {document} \par \par \par \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of __fp_to_decimal_recover:w.  How to correct \NewDocumentCommand{\eval}{mo} command ?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem,siunitx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\eval}{mm}
     { #1 =
    \group_begin:
      \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
      \cs_set:Npn \frac ##1##2 {##1/(##2)}
      \cs_set:Npn \times { * }
      \cs_set:Npn \pi { pi }
      \cs_set:Npn \sqrt ##1 { (##1)**.5 }
      \cs_set:Npe \__xcn_tmp:w ##1 { \token_to_str:N ^ (##1) }
      \char_set_active_eq:NN ^ \__xcn_tmp:w
      \tl_set_rescan:Nne \l_tmpa_tl { \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\^ } }
        { \l_tmpa_tl }
      \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
      \tl_gset:Nn  \l_tmpb_tl  { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } } 
    \exp_args:NNNV \group_end:
   \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl   \l_tmpb_tl 
   %%%
   \IfValueT{#2}{
          \fp_zero_new:c { l_xcn_var_#2_fp } 
          \fp_gset:cn  { l_xcn_var_#2_fp } { \l_tmpb_tl  } 
        }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_xcn_var_#1_fp }
 }

\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usefpvar}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

$\eval{\pi/2+\sqrt{5}}{aa}$

\?{aa}


\end{document}

% ------------------------------------

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem,siunitx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\eval}{mo}
     { #1 =
    \group_begin:
      \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
      \cs_set:Npn \frac ##1##2 {##1/(##2)}
      \cs_set:Npn \times { * }
      \cs_set:Npn \pi { pi }
      \cs_set:Npn \sqrt ##1 { (##1)**.5 }
      \cs_set:Npe \__cs_tmp:w ##1 { \token_to_str:N ^ (##1) }
      \char_set_active_eq:NN ^ \__cs_tmp:w
      \tl_set_rescan:Nne \l_tmpa_tl { \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\^ } }
        { \l_tmpa_tl }
      \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
      \tl_gset:Nn  \l_tmpb_tl  { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } } 
    \exp_args:NNNV \group_end:
   \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl   \l_tmpb_tl 
   %%%
   \IfValueT{#2}{
          \fp_zero_new:c { l_xcn_var_#2_fp } 
          \fp_gset:cn  { l_xcn_var_#2_fp } { \l_tmpb_tl  } 
        }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_xcn_var_#1_fp }
 }

\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usefpvar}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

$\eval{\pi/2+\sqrt{6}}{aa}$

\?{aa}

$\eval{4*5}$

\end{document}





Don't use \__cs_tmp:w to set up a temporary meaning, you should use \__xcn_tmp:w instead, your module isn't cs, that's part of L3.

Thanks @Skillmon for your tips. the module has been edited.

Just spotted this: You shouldn't use \tl_gset:Nn \l_tmpb_tl, that's a global assignment to a local variable. Use \tl_gset:Nn \g_tmpb_tl instead.

Though you don't even need that variable at all, you could just use \cs_new_protected:Npn \__xcn_eval_finalize:nn #1#2 { #1 \IfValueT {#2} { \fp_zero_new:c { g_xcn_var_#2_fp } \fp_gset:cn { g_xcn_var_#2_fp } {#1} } } and then \exp_args:NNe \group_end: \__xcn_eval_finalize:nn { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } } {#2}. Also your variables use a local name but you're assigning them globally (already corrected in my code in this comment).

thanks @Skillmon for your valuble advice. I will edit the above code later.

@Skillmon  I encounter an error when compiling : ! Use of \__xcn_eval_finalize:nn doesn't match its definition. Could you give a full example ?

The definition works fine. Only the usage uses erroneous syntax. The second argument is option so, if given, it must use square rather than curly brackets. So when the first \eval is read, no second argument is found. The {aa} is imply typeset as it is not absorbed by \eval. This causes an error when you try to use the variable with \?{aa} because the variable has not been defined.
Simply change the {} to [] in the first use of \eval and it all compiles fine.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_xcn_var_#1_fp }
 }
\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usefpvar}
\NewDocumentCommand{\eval}{mo}
{ #1 =
  \group_begin:
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \cs_set:Npn \frac ##1##2 {##1/(##2)}
    \cs_set:Npn \times { * }
    \cs_set:Npn \pi { pi }
    \cs_set:Npn \sqrt ##1 { (##1)**.5 }
    \cs_set:Npe \__xcn_tmp:w ##1 { \token_to_str:N ^ (##1) }
    \char_set_active_eq:NN ^ \__xcn_tmp:w
    \tl_set_rescan:Nne \l_tmpa_tl { \char_set_catcode_active:n { `\^ } } { \l_tmpa_tl }
    \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \l_tmpa_tl }
    \tl_gset:Nn  \l_tmpb_tl  { \fp_eval:n { \l_tmpa_tl } }
    \exp_args:NNNV
  \group_end:
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_tl
  \l_tmpb_tl
  %%%
  \IfValueT{#2}{
    \fp_zero_new:c { l_xcn_var_#2_fp }
    \fp_gset:cn  { l_xcn_var_#2_fp } { \l_tmpb_tl  }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\eval{\pi/2+\sqrt{5}}[aa]$

\?{aa}

$\eval{4*5}$

\end{document}

Note that your argument was not especially minimal, so I minimised it somewhat by removing most of the irrelevant packages.

thanks @cfr for  pointing out my mistakes.

@xcn it is very easy to do and you have not chosen to set this up in a way which provides informative feedback when something goes wrong. tex isn't great at this out-of-the-box and there are some limits to what is possible, but I find it is generally a good idea to build interfaces which at least try to tell me something useful when I screw up. I'm not especially good at doing that, but I've learnt it is worth trying. (when I first wrote my own commands, I only thought about how convenient they'd be when used correctly. that was a mistake I suspect you are tempted to make too.)

Yes. I believe better interfaces will come true. I forget to use square brackets for optional argument after my busy working recently.

@xcn yes, but if you used the standard order i.e. optional argument first, you would probably figure out the mistake more easily. not guaranteed as it depends on the details, but generally. because, in that case, you'd get an error complaining it isn't possible to do arithmetic with aa and that is much more of a clue to what's wrong than an error which shows up only later on a perfectly correct line. that's all I meant. the error would also be reported on the right line and not, possibly, pages later.

I plan to place something ahead . the command like \NewDocumentCommand{\eval}{O{15}mo}  .  The first optional argument is used to round decimal and the last is for assignment.

@xcn if you don't want a key-value approach, I would put both optionals first and just use different delimiters e.g. \NewDocumentCommand{\eval}{ O{15} d () m }{...} or whatever. then you can still distinguish the two options, but you also get the benefits of coming before the mandatory argument for both. when you don't want a mandatory argument atll, things are obviously different. but, where you do, I think it makes sense to use it to help with catching errors.

thanks@cfr  It looks more neat and orderly to put optionals first in addition to catching errors. I will change my habit.
